# Firebase error saving rules, Line 1: mismatched input

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

How can I resolve this error in Firestore security rules?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the rules version line at the top and also the syntax you are using is for Firebase realtime database. Try the following rules for Firestore.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```